# GeoTools GML 3.2 serialization - how to access GMLConfiguration and GML namespace

Tags: geotools, gml, jts-topology-suite

I am using code similar to the sample below to serialize JTS geometries to GML 3.2. That works fine, but I can't see how to access the underlying configuration in order to control aspects of GML serialization.

E.g., where I have 8 significant digits in JTS, the GML serialization only preserves 7:

```
POINT (8.7654321 1.2345678)
```

converts to:

```xml
<gml:Point srsDimension="2">
   <gml:pos>8.765432 1.234568</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
```

Apparently this is caused by the setting of [`numDecimals`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/3553a627de870bb7b0c347da271ad148dab988f3/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-gml3/src/main/java/org/geotools/gml3/GMLConfiguration.java#L129-L130) in the [`GMLConfiguration`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/gml3/GMLConfiguration.html) class,

```java
    /** Number of decimals that should be used for formatting numbers */
    private int numDecimals = 6;
```

and this could even be changed by invoking [`setNumDecimals`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/3553a627de870bb7b0c347da271ad148dab988f3/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-gml3/src/main/java/org/geotools/gml3/GMLConfiguration.java#L377-L384),

```java
    /**
     * Sets the number of decimals that should be used for encoding coordinates
     *
     * @param numDecimals the numDecimals to set
     */
    public void setNumDecimals(int numDecimals) {
        this.numDecimals = numDecimals;
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to use the API to access the actual GMLConfiguration that is used when my code is executed. How can I prevent loss of precision?

The other problem is the `gml` namespace in the result, which presents the GML 2 namespace, `http://www.opengis.net/gml`, even though the result structure is GML 3. How can I make it use the GML 3.2 namespace, `http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2`?

This is my code:

```java
package geotools.test;

import java.net.URL;

import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2;
import org.geotools.wfs.GML;
import org.geotools.wfs.GML.Version;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;

public class JtsGeometryToGmlSample {
  private final static String namespaceURI = "http://example.org/geo";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Geometry jtsGeometry =
        new WKTReader2().read("POINT (8.7654321 1.2345678)");
    System.out.println(jtsGeometry + "\n");

    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder typeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    typeBuilder.setName("feature");
    typeBuilder.setNamespaceURI(namespaceURI);
    typeBuilder.add("geometry", Geometry.class);
    SimpleFeatureType featureType = typeBuilder.buildFeatureType();

    SimpleFeature feature = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType)
        .buildFeature(null, new Object[] {jtsGeometry});
    DefaultFeatureCollection collection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
    collection.add(feature);

    GML gml = new GML(Version.WFS1_1);
    gml.setNamespace("geo", namespaceURI);
    gml.setBaseURL(new URL(namespaceURI));
    gml.encode(System.out, collection);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

And the result is:

```xml
POINT (8.7654321 1.2345678)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:geo="http://example.org/geo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope>
      <gml:lowerCorner>8.765432 1.234568</gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>8.765432 1.234568</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMembers>
    <geo:feature gml:id="fid-5906bc5a_18a17d5ad55_-8000">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope>
          <gml:lowerCorner>8.765432 1.234568</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>8.765432 1.234568</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <geo:geometry>
        <gml:Point srsDimension="2">
          <gml:pos>8.765432 1.234568</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </geo:geometry>
    </geo:feature>
  </gml:featureMembers>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: 17 digits is way too many ~ https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: @nmtoken, good point, but who am I to limit precision at the transport level?

Comment: It was never that precise to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the precision can be done by inlining the `encode` method and fixing the configuration that is going to be used. This is accomplished by adding a few imports,

```java
import static org.geotools.wfs.WFS.FeatureCollection;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
import org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration;
import org.geotools.wfs.v1_1.WFSConfiguration;
import org.geotools.xsd.Configuration;
import org.geotools.xsd.Encoder;
```

then replacing this code

```java
GML gml = new GML(Version.WFS1_1);
gml.setNamespace("geo", namespaceURI);
gml.setBaseURL(new URL(namespaceURI));
gml.encode(System.out, collection);
```

by this

```java
WFSConfiguration configuration = new WFSConfiguration();
configuration.getProperties().add(GMLConfiguration.OPTIMIZED_ENCODING);
fixConfiguration(configuration);
Encoder gml32Encoder = new Encoder(configuration);
gml32Encoder.getNamespaces().declarePrefix("geo", namespaceURI);
gml32Encoder.setIndenting(true);
FeatureCollectionType featureCollectionType = WfsFactory.eINSTANCE.createFeatureCollectionType();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
EList<DefaultFeatureCollection> eList = featureCollectionType.getFeature();
eList.add(collection);
gml32Encoder.encode(featureCollectionType, FeatureCollection, System.out);
```

and finally adding this method that establishes the precision value:

```java
private static void fixConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
  if (configuration instanceof org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration)
    ((org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration) configuration).setNumDecimals(7);
  for (Configuration dependency : configuration.getDependencies())
    fixConfiguration(dependency);
}
```

I have not found a way to get the namespace right, so I'll resort to changing the result accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mess with the internals of the `GMLConfiguration` then you will a need to to build your own parser, have a look inside the GML code to see how it is done.

You could also make an enhancement request to allow users access to the configuration inside the GML classes.